# How do I get two conditional statements to pull information onto the same column?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a requirement to do a calculation under two conditions but have the output appear in the same column `Erisa (Local)`.
I need to check if there is a value in a column `ERISA Percentage` and, if so, multiply that value by another column "Net Amount (Local)".
If the `ERISA Percentage` column has no value I want to check the `ERISA Status` column for a specific word `Erisa`. If the row has that word then I need to pull in the value in column `Net Amount Local`.

I tried an `elif` statement and an or statement but am getting an invalid syntax error. Does anyone know what amendment I should make to the code below?

```
ecdi['Erisa (Local)'] = ecdi.apply(lambda x: x['Net Amount (Local)']  * x['ERISA Percentage']/100 if x['ERISA Percentage']>0 and x['ERISA Status'] == "Erisa"

elif ecdi['Erisa (Local)'] = ecdi.apply(lambda x: x['Net Amount (Local)'] if x['ERISA Percentage'] == 0 and x['ERISA Status'] == "Erisa"                        
                                                               else 0, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to do as vectorised calculations for performance.  Hence I've used `np.where`

1. reversed your logic,  to default to *zero* when *percentage* is less than equal to zero and *status* is not *Erisa*
2. standard calc if percentage is > *zero*
3. leaves one case,  it's *Erisa* and percentage < *zero*
4. for good measure I added a column *check* to better test logic is working as defined

```
r = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({"ERISA Percentage":[random.randint(-25,100) for i in range(r)],
 "Net Amount (Local)":[random.randint(50,125) for i in range(r)],
 "ERISA Status":[["Erisa","a","b"][random.randint(0,2)] for i in range(r)]
})

df = df.assign(**{"Erisa (Local)":lambda dfa: 
             np.where((dfa["ERISA Percentage"]<=0) & (dfa["ERISA Status"]!="Erisa"), 0, 
                     np.where(dfa["ERISA Percentage"]>0, 
                              dfa["ERISA Percentage"]/100*dfa["Net Amount (Local)"],
                              dfa["Net Amount (Local)"])),
             "check":lambda dfa: dfa["Erisa (Local)"]==dfa["Net Amount (Local)"]
            })

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
 ERISA Percentage  Net Amount (Local) ERISA Status  Erisa (Local)  check
               79                  56        Erisa          44.24  False
               68                 124            b          84.32  False
               33                 124        Erisa          40.92  False
              -21                 100            b           0.00  False
               42                 124            b          52.08  False
               -5                  76            b           0.00  False
               38                  95        Erisa          36.10  False
               20                 109            b          21.80  False
               55                  63            a          34.65  False
              -13                 106        Erisa         106.00   True
```